# How to get date in UTC time zone using Dataweave

Tags: timezone, dataweave, mulesoft

I have the following dataweave expression that displays the time and date that is 90 days before today's date in my local timezone (IST), I want to get the timezone as GMT+00:00 instead of GMT+05:30

**my dataweave expression:**

```
%dw 2.0 var time= now() output application/json

---
{
    "date" : time - ("P$(90)D" as Period)
}
```

**current output:**

```
{ 
   "date": "2020-11-12T09:14:15.908+05:30"
}
```

**desired output**

```
{ 
   "date": "2020-11-12T09:14:15.908+00:00"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

there are so many ways to show the timeZone , I let you know one example that I have tried for you
**your input was now()**

```
%dw 2.0 
var time= now() 
output application/json
---
{
"date": (now() >> 'UTC') as DateTime {format: "dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss.SSSSSSSSS a VV"} as String {format: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss:SSS Z"}
}
```

**the output of this code is:**

```
{
  "date": "2021-02-10T07:09:11:815 +0000"
}
```

Note: There is no time difference between Greenwich Mean Time (GMT) and Coordinated Universal Time (UTC)

This code you can easily modify according to your requirement for example if you want the same code for GMT +5:30 that is Asia/Calcutta time Zone ID

that will be as below

```
%dw 2.0 
var time= now() 
output application/json
---
{
"date": (now() >> 'Asia/Calcutta') as DateTime {format: "dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss.SSSSSSSSS a VV"} as String {format: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss:SSS Z"}
}
```

so main point is here that you need to specify the time zone ID to get that in your output
and this is the official document link that shows a list of all Time Zone ID's in mulesoft at the present day (10-02-2021)- https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dataweave-cookbook-change-time-zone

Thanks

Comment: Thanks anurag, I'll give a try, thanks for being descriptive.

Comment: Ok Ravi good, Please try and let us know the audience by upvoting the answer as this is useful and mark as accepted if it resolve issue. Thanks

Comment: That URL no longer works.  Has the content been moved to https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dataweave-cookbook-change-time-zone ?

Comment: yes, it is moved here now https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dataweave-cookbook-change-time-zone